# Apache Reverse Proxy Redirect Error

Tags: apache

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with LAMP installed on a VPS. I also have installed mod_proxy and related modules. I have a backend application running with dotnet listening on localhost:5000. I've modified /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf to

ProxyPreserveHost On

```
# Servers to proxy the connection, or;
# List of application servers:
# Usage:
# ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
# ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
# Example: 
ProxyPass /app http://localhost:5000/
ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:5000/

ServerName localhost
```

When I try and access 00.00.00.00/app in my browser, I get the following error with the Apache screen:

The requested URL /Login was not found on this server

However, when I turn off my dotnet application, I get a Service Unavailable error when I try and access the same link in my browser. So its doing something.

00.00.00.00 is the VPS IP.

Note I followed this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

Comment: Where does the `/Login` come from?

Comment: And are you sure you want to use `ServerName localhost` on a VPS with static IP?

Comment: /login is what the application on the backend is redirecting to. What's wrong with using just localhost? Apologies for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Using `localhost` as a server name _may_ cause several issues. But that is not the issue here.

Comment: In the code for the application, I entered localhost there too in the database settings for SQL. Apparently I'm meant to use reverse proxy to reroute traffic from port 80 to localhost:5000 according to some documentation.  Isn't that whats happening here?

Comment: The proxy setup looks fine to me.

Comment: Make sure to clear your browsers cache and retry.

Comment: Tried that. No luck. I tried it on a different PC aswell same thing

Comment: Ok, then you will have to dig deeper to understand what is actually going on before you can solve the issue. Please take a look at the actual redirection header sent. Where does the URL point to? You can see that in your browsers development console. You should compare that to what happens if you request the apps internal URL directly.

Comment: I just got it working. I removed the /app in the proxy settings, and it started working. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Sorry, can't follow. I assume you wanted to publish that internal service under the URL `https://example.org/app` just as you wrote. So you changed your plans?

Comment: I did. It doesn't seem to be working. I'm assuming it's some issue with the application. I'd prefer it to be on /app. I might have a deeper look in the code